# select node ranges using XPath

Tags: java, xpath

We are using XPath in a Java app and I was wondering: How do I select a set of nodes where the "terminating point" is a node not belonging to the same kind as it's siblings.

For example, I want to get two sets of `<a>` tags of size 3 and 2 from the example below:

```
<sample>
   <a />
   <a />
   <a />
   <terminating />
   <a />
   <a />   
</sample>
```

Comment: I can't see your example. Please post a complete (or complete within itself) XML file.

Comment: Post fixed. @ola_user: Have a look at the editor help box on the right side of the screen for your next post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the result of an XPath expression is always either an atomic value, or a single node-set (or sequence in XPath 2.0). You cannot get a list of node-sets.

That said, for your specific example with just two groups and one terminator, you can just use `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`:

```
/sample/terminating/preceding-sibling::a
/sample/terminating/following-sibling::a
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Pavel Minaev's answer - I would write a loop, like this ("`i`" being the loop index):

- find all the `<terminating>` nodes with the help of
  → `/sample/terminating`
- for each of them, find all the
  → `./preceding-sibling::a[count(preceding-sibling::terminating) = {i}]`
- for the last `<terminating>` node, also find the
  → `./following-sibling::a`

Comment: I think it could be done even easier - given `$i`, it would be just `/sample/a[count(preceding-sibling::terminating) = $i - 1]` to get all `a` in `$i`th group.

Comment: You are right, this would give the same result. Complexity is about the same, though.